# Symfon2 - enable logging 'info' in production

Tags: symfony, logging, info

I have this code:

```
         $logger = $this->get('logger');
         $logger->info('Test');
```

Works fine in dev but it is ignored in production. How can I force to log this in production too?

Comment: when you encounter an error do you get a blank white page or do you get a status 500 message? and you may also want to edit you tag from 'symfon2' to 'symfony2'. could be the reason for low views count :P

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at your monolog config on app/config/config_prod.yml by default has as action level: error

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main:
            type:         fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler:      nested
```

See that for the full reference: http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/monolog.html